# How to use NokiaMap for WP7

Tags: windows-phone-7, maps, bing-maps, here-api

I'm trying to use a NokiaMaps for windows phone 7 and I've tried follow from this sites: 
http://developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Nokia_Maps_for_WP7_using_Bing_Map_Control.

But "MapTileLayer" as Hybrid,Physical,Street,Satellite... does not work !

I think this problem is UriFomat but i can't solve.

Can you please tell me the reason ?

Answer (score 0):

For using the Bing Map control successfully you need to obtain a Bing Map Token (NokiaMapTile.cs, topic 4). You can obtain it here: https://www.bingmapsportal.com/

Beware that when requesting the token you need to specify the same app name as the test one (in this case NokiaMaps).
And be sure to update the .cs and .xaml files with your newly created token data.

Regards,

Comment: Sorry, my mistake on the Token Link, you should use the Nokia Maps Token and App ID on http://developer.here.net/. For help how to generate it check: http://developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/How_to_Obtain_Your_Own_Nokia_appID_and_Token I tired it on my WP 7.8 and works fine (it takes some time to load the map but I think it is a connection issue on my side)

Comment: ...also, for some reason it works only on my device and not in the emulator, but again it might me an emulator connection problem.